# NETLOGO - setting properties on list elements

Tags: list, properties, netlogo

I'm new to to new netlogo and I'm having osme issues working with lists.

I globaly define a variable to be my list and add 2 patches to it, but then while trying to set properties such as color i get an error saying "Expected command".

Here is some sample code :

```
globals[lhole]

to generate-burrow
   ifelse crab-number = 1 [set hole patch 0 0]
   [let hole1 patch random-pxcor random-pycor 
   let hole2 patch random-pxcor random-pycor 
   set lhole [] set lhole lput hole1 lhole set lhole lput hole2 lhole]  
end

to setup
  create-entrance crab-number [                            
    ifelse crab-number = 1
    [home set shape "circle"
      set color black]
    [first lhole set shape "circle" set color black
     last lhole set shape "circle" set color black
    ]
  ]
end
```

If i click on the Check sign it highlights `first` and gives the `"Expected command"` error.

Answer (score 2):

The reporter `first` provides the value of the first item in the list, but you haven't told NetLogo what to do with it. For example, do you want to print it, or assign it to some variable? Create an empty model and try the following code to see two possibilities of how to use it.

```
to testme
  let mylist (list 2 4 6 8)
  print mylist
  type "first item is " print first mylist
  let myvalue first mylist
  type "myvalue is " print myvalue
end
```